# Append dynamic stats on attribute table in QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

I have an attribute table containing records like Town, inhabitants, N° male, N° Female like this:

When I compose a map in QGIS I use "Show only visible feature" command resulting in a view with only few records. 
I need to add a last dynamic row or separate custom table with statistics (based only on visible features) to summarize my table with:

- Inhabitans sum,
- n°male sum
- n°female sum
- male/female ratio

How can I do in QGIS Map Composer?